# Cannot create 2 foreign keys in one table using EF6

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sql-server-2008-r2, entity-framework-6

I am using VS 2013, SQL Server 2008 R2. I just started learning ASP.NET MVC & EF.

I have created two classes:

```
public class Album
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    //ApplicationUser from Asp.net Identity Model
    public ApplicationUser Artist; //Who Part
    public DateTime DateTime { get; set; } //When Part
    public string Venue { get; set; } //Where Part
    public Genre Genre { get; set; } //Type Part
}

public class Genre
{
    public byte Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

When I create `add-migration CreateAlbum`, I should get two foreign keys but I am getting only one i.e. from `Genre` (`Genre_Id`).

How to resolve this? I want to link `ApplicationUser` (`Artist_Id`) i.e. AspnetUser to my `Album` table

Comment: I think you want to map different `tables` to one `table Album`.. am i right?

Comment: yes I want to map two tables i.e. AspnetUser, Genre to AlbumTable

Comment: Then use `Table Splitting` in EF .. [this](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/ff2f08/table-splitting-in-entity-framework-6-code-first-approach/) and [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj715645.aspx) would be heplful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to set **get and set**. Add get and set in your class for Application user.

```
public class Album
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    //ApplicationUser from Asp.net Identity Model
    public ApplicationUser Artist { get; set; }; //Who Part
    public DateTime DateTime { get; set; } //When Part
    public string Venue { get; set; } //Where Part
    public Genre Genre { get; set; } //Type Part
}

public class Genre
{
    public byte Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Now run migration. it will work.